# Python inheritance not working as I expected

Tags: python, oop, python-3.5

I have a class -

```
class Start(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = False
        self.my_list = []
    def set_up(self):
        self.flag = True
    def end_set_up(self):
        self.my_list = [i*2 for i in self.my_list]
```

And another class which inherits from this class -

```
class Process(Start):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Process, self).__init__()
    def check_flag(self):
        if self.flag:
            self.my_list = range(1, 10)
```

And in the third class, I want to do some operations on `my_list`

```
class Operation(Start):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Operation, self).__init__()        
    def perform_op(self):
        self.my_list = [i*2 for i in self.my_list]
```

Now these classes are used in a code snippet as -

```
start_ob = Start()
start_ob.set_up()
process_ob = Process()
process_ob.check_flag()
op_ob = Operation()
op_ob.perform_op()
```

My understanding of classes is not that strong. What I thought of achieving with this was -

- Set up class `Start()`
- Inherit flag from class `Start()` into `Process()` which should be `True` now since I called `set_up()` function here `start_ob.set_up()`
- Set `my_list` in base class to be `[1,2....9]`
- Inherit `Start()` into `Operation()` and modify list `[1,2....9]` that I created in the object `Process()`

But things are not moving according to my understanding. `my_list` is empty as `set_up` is `False` for classes `Process` and `Operation`. How do I change my code to make it work according to what my understanding is?

**Edit**- In the base class, there are two methods, one has to run when the object is initialised, right at the beginning. It will set a flag to True. After which another method in the same base class needs to run according to that flag

Comment: All your objects are independent with their own instance variables. It seems like you are expecting to some form of prototypal inheritance (a la javascript) but class-based inheritance is different.

Comment: Thing is in the base class, there are two methods, one has to run when the object is initialised, right at the beginning. It will set a flag to True. After which another method in the same base class needs to run according to that flag

Comment: Yes, but you have created *three independent objects*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think I understand what you are saying. So how do I go about solving this?

Comment: If you want a flag set to True when you create an object, why don't you set `self.flag = True`?

Comment: Don't create three independent objects. See abarnart's answer. Your inheritance is still broken (see my comment on his answer), but that would be a start.

Comment: @SunnyPatel probably irrelevant in Python 3.

Comment: @SunnyPatel sorry, that's how I was using it in my code, edited

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you say inheritance is still broken. Why would that be and how should I solve that?

Comment: @SunnyPatel added the tag to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

What you’re doing here:

```
start_ob = Start()
start_ob.set_up()
process_ob = Process()
process_ob.check_flag()
op_ob = Operation()
op_ob.perform_op()
```

… is creating three entirely separate objects. Each one has its own `my_list`. Just like you can have three different `int` objects and they’re all separate values, you can have three different `Start` objects and they’re all separate values.

What you probably wanted is:

```
ob = Operation()
ob.set_up()
ob.check_flag()
ob.perform_op()
```

Now you have a single object, which is an `Operation`, and therefore a `Process`, and therefore a `Start`, so you can call methods from any of those three types and they will affect your object’s value. And now you’re using inheritance.

Comment: Note, `Operation` isn't inheriting from `Process`, they are sister classes. It won't have `check_flag`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. Can you see whether my edited question affects your answer?

Comment: But we can't call `check_flag` from `Operation` class as `check_flag` is a function of `Process` not `Operation`?